# Does firebase ever recycle tokens?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app which is receiving a token from firebase.  From what I understand, the next step would be to assign that token to a user in my database, perhaps in a "lastFirebaseToken" column.  Then I could call the firebase api using this token to send messages to a specific device.  If any of this is wrong, my question won't make sense, but assuming all of the above:

**Would there ever be point at which a token that was assigned to a device in the past gets re-assigned to a different device?**

In any case, I'll probably make the `lastFirebaseToken` column UNIQUE, but I still find this question important to my fundamental understanding of firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the tokens should be unique.

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#credentials):

> Registration token
>
> A **unique token** string that identifies each client app instance. The
>   registration token is required for single device and device group
>   messaging. Note that registration tokens must be kept secret.